# project run in iOS simulator, but did not build project in react native

Tags: xcode, react-native

warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.3.99. (in target 'Flipper' from project 'Pods')

** BUILD FAILED **

The following build commands failed:
Ld /Users/ramprasadsarkar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AwesomeProject-edxfscsdfjwsmicnfanfokvrokke/Build/Intermediates.noindex/AwesomeProject.build/Release-iphonesimulator/AwesomeProject.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Binary/AwesomeProject normal arm64

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following.

- If you are using terminal then set directory to your app folder.
- or if you are using Vscode just open the terminal.
- I hope you have already installed node.(did basic setup).

In terminal add follwing commands one by one, means use next commands only after completing 1 st command run.

`npm install`

`cd ios`

`pod install`

`cd ..`

`npm run ios` or `npx react-native run-ios`

Just check it works.